# Detox Tests Hang in BeforeAll Hook for Android, but not iOS

Tags: javascript, cucumberjs, detox

**Description**

Detox tests are hanging on the `init` call on Android emulator. The app is installed on the emulator, but never launches. The same tests execute over the same application on the iOS simulator. I am using `Cucumber` for the test runner and am just calling the `init` function in the `BeforeAll` hook.

**hooks.js**

```
const {Before, BeforeAll, AfterAll} = require('cucumber');
const detox = require('detox');

const detoxConfig = require('../../../package.json').detox;

BeforeAll({timeout: 60 * 1000}, async () => {
    await detox.init(detoxConfig);
});
```

**package.json**

```
    "detox": {
    "configurations": {
        "android.emu.debug": {
            "binaryPath": "android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk",
            "build": "cd android && ./gradlew assembleDebug assembleAndroidTest -DtestBuildType=debug && cd ..",
            "type": "android.emulator",
            "name": "Pixel_2",
            "session": {
                "server": "ws://localhost:8099",
                "sessionId": "androidDebug"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Detox, Node, Device, and macOS Versions**

Detox: 7.3.3

Node: 8.9.4

Emulator: Android Studio default w/ API 24 (7.0)

macOS: High Sierra Version 10.13.3

React-Native: 0.55.2

React: 16.0.0

**Detox Server Logs**

```
MBP-55EE:detox-android$ detox run-server
detox-server info 12:14:32: server listening on localhost:8099...
detox-server wss 12:14:48: role=tester login (sessionId=androidDebug)
detox-server wss 12:14:48: role=tester action=loginSuccess 
(sessionId=androidDebug)
detox-server wss 12:14:53: role=tester action=isReady 
(sessionId=androidDebug)
detox-server wss 12:14:53: role=testee not connected, cannot fw action 
(sessionId=androidDebug)
detox-server wss 12:15:48: role=tester disconnect 
(sessionId=androidDebug)
```

What sticks out to me is on iOS the tests complete, but I still see the line about the testee not being connected, so I am at a loss.

**All things equal except this is run on iOS Simulator in XCode 9**

```
MBP-55EE:detox-android$ detox run-server
detox-server info 10:53:28: server listening on localhost:8099...
detox-server wss 10:54:27: role=tester login (sessionId=debugSession)
detox-server wss 10:54:27: role=tester action=loginSuccess 
(sessionId=debugSession)
detox-server wss 10:54:44: role=tester action=isReady 
(sessionId=debugSession)
detox-server wss 10:54:44: role=testee not connected, cannot fw action 
(sessionId=debugSession)
detox-server wss 10:54:49: role=testee login (sessionId=debugSession)
detox-server wss 10:54:49: role=testee action=loginSuccess 
(sessionId=debugSession)
detox-server wss 10:54:49: role=testee action=ready 
(sessionId=debugSession)
detox-server wss 10:54:49: role=tester action=invoke 
(sessionId=debugSession)
detox-server wss 10:54:49: role=testee action=invokeResult 
(sessionId=debugSession)
detox-server wss 10:54:49: role=tester action=invoke 
(sessionId=debugSession)
detox-server wss 10:54:50: role=testee action=invokeResult 
(sessionId=debugSession)
detox-server wss 10:54:50: role=tester action=invoke 
(sessionId=debugSession)
detox-server wss 10:54:50: role=testee action=invokeResult 
(sessionId=debugSession)
...
```

Any ideas on why iOS works as expected, but Android does not?

Comment: Have you tried newer versions of Detox with Android?